# Title of each image in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am making a slideshow for a site.
The images need to be background images, and I need the image title as a quote on top of the image.
The problem is that it shows the title of the first background-image on all the images. Somehow I need to get the title of the individual images.

```
var $sliderImages = $('.slideshow .field-name-field-image-carousel img');
var $sliderImagesTitle = $sliderImages.attr('title');

    $sliderImages.each(function(i, elem) {                          // create divs
      var img = $(elem);
      var div = $("<div class='sliderImage' />").css({
        background: "url(" + img.attr("src") + ") no-repeat",
      }).append("<figcaption><span>" + $sliderImagesTitle + "</span></figcaption>");
      img.replaceWith(div);                                         // replace images with divs
    });

    $('.sliderImage').wrap("<figure />");                           // start by wrapping the rendered images
    $('.slideshow figure:first-of-type').addClass('show');          // and choose which one to display first
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the getter version of `.attr()` in a set of elements, it will return the attribute value of the first element in the set, not of other elements.

Since you are iterating through all the image elements, you can just read the value with the loop

```
var $sliderImages = $('.slideshow .field-name-field-image-carousel img');

$sliderImages.each(function (i, elem) { // create divs
    var img = $(elem);
    var div = $("<div class='sliderImage' />").css({
        background: "url(" + img.attr("src") + ") no-repeat",
    }).append("<figcaption><span>" + img.attr('title') + "</span></figcaption>");
    img.replaceWith(div); // replace images with divs
});

$('.sliderImage').wrap("<figure />"); // start by wrapping the rendered images
$('.slideshow figure:first-of-type').addClass('show');
```